# The value of dropdown after posting from IE7/8, displays as array, but normal value in firefox using PHP,HTML,JAVA(DHTMLSUITE modal message)

Tags: java, php, html

i am generating a dropdown in a twin forloop ( for loop inside a forloop)

when i post the same with IE7/8 i get the values as an array(array { [0] = 11_31_2}), but in firefox i get it as 11_31_2.

below is the following code i use

```
for ($k=1;$k<=strlen($weeklist);$k++) {
    if ($presentweek == 1) {
        $k = 0;
    }
    if (substr($weeklist,$k-1,1) == 1 || $presentweek == 1) {
        if ($presentweek == 1) {
            $presentweek++;
        }
        $selectedweekstarttime = $starttime + (60*60*24*7*$k);
        $selectedweekendtime = $selectedweekstarttime + (60*60*24*6);
        foreach ($meterreadergroup as $meterreader_id) {
            $readerid_selected = $readerselect == "" ? $meterreader_id : $readerselect;
            $has_rule = getPlanningRuleOfTheWeek ($readerid_selected,$selectedweekstarttime);
            $has_freeweek = getFreeTimeOfTheWeek ($readerid_selected,$selectedweekstarttime);
            if ($has_rule != "" || $has_freeweek != "") {
                if (stripos($problemweek,$getweeks[$k]) === false) {
                    $problemweek = $problemweek.$getweeks[$k].";";
                }
                $filldetails = "";
                if (is_array($has_rule)) {
                    $filldetails .= "Has Planningrules<br />";
                }
                if (is_array($has_freeweek)) {
                    $filldetails .= "Has freeweek/day";
                }
                $selectdetails = "";
                print "getweeks - ".$getweeks[$k]."<br>";
                $selectdetails .= "<select errorcheck='checkoptions' name='".$readerid_selected."_".$getweeks[$k]."' onchange='clearErrorFields(this,".$x.");'>
                <option value='".$readerid_selected."_".$getweeks[$k]."_0'>Choose Solution</option>
                <option value='".$readerid_selected."_".$getweeks[$k]."_1'>Leave this week for this meterreader out when copying</option>
                <option value='".$readerid_selected."_".$getweeks[$k]."_2'>Leave this entire week out when copying</option>
                <option value='".$readerid_selected."_".$getweeks[$k]."_3'>Remove current rules for meterreader and force new rules</option>
                </select>";
                $row_details[] = array($getweeks[$k],fetchMeterreaderDetails("vnaam,tv,anaam",$readerid_selected),$filldetails,$selectdetails,"<div id='error".$x."' ></div>");
                $x++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

for example

name='".$readerid_selected."_".$getweeks[$k]."'
eample name='11_31'

value='".$readerid_selected."_".$getweeks[$k]."_0'
value ='11_31_2'

so when i $_REQUEST['11_31'] i expect the value as 11_31_2
i only get the value i expected in firefox,
but for me in IE7/8 i get the value as array{ [0] = 11_31_2}

Answer (score 0):

This is a stab in the dark, but it's possible that IE is choking on the nonstandard "errorcheck='checkoptions'" attribute. I say this because the behavior you report (getting selection as an array) is what you'd expect from a <select multiple>, so maybe possibly there's a bug in IE, triggered by the nonstandard attribute, that makes it submit the element like a multiple select.